# Unable to implement solution by using .keyup, .keydown ,.keypress

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, keypress, keydown

I am trying to write a code which will enable me to fill cell phone no. field with less efforts, my code is as follows.

**HTML**

```
<div class="control-group">
   <label class="control-label" for="inputPhone">Cell Phone Number #:</label>
      <div class="controls"> 
      <?php 
         $home_no=$blogger_info[0]->home_phone;
         $home_phone=explode('-',$home_no);
       ?>
       <input class="span3 mr-botom-10" type="tel" id="HomePhone1" name="HomePhone1" value="<?=$home_phone[0]; ?>" onkeydown="phoneNumberValidate('HomePhone1',3,'HomePhone2')" maxlength="3"  pattern="<?php echo NUMBER_PATTERN_3_DIG; ?>" title="<?php echo NUMBER_PATTERN_3_MSG; ?>">   
       <input class="span3 mr-botom-10" type="tel" id="HomePhone2" name="HomePhone2" value="<?=$home_phone[1]; ?>" onkeydown="phoneNumberValidate('HomePhone2',3,'HomePhone3')" maxlength="3"  pattern="<?php echo NUMBER_PATTERN_3_DIG; ?>" title="<?php echo NUMBER_PATTERN_3_MSG; ?>">                                           
       <input class="span3 mr-botom-10" type="tel" id="HomePhone3" name="HomePhone3"  value="<?=$home_phone[2]; ?>" onkeydown="phoneNumberValidate('HomePhone3',4,'')" maxlength="4"  pattern="<?php echo NUMBER_PATTERN_4_DIG; ?>" title="<?php echo NUMBER_PATTERN_4_MSG; ?>">    
     </div>
 </div>
```

**JS code:**

```
function phoneNumberValidate(phone1,match_len,phone2)
{

  //called when key is pressed in textbox
  $("#"+phone1).keypress(function (e) 
  {
     //if the letter is not digit then display error and don't type anything
         if (e.which != 8 && e.which != 0 && (e.which < 48 || e.which > 57)) 
         {
             return false;
         }
         else
         {
          var phone=$("#"+phone1).val();

          var field_len=phone.length;


           if(field_len==match_len && e.which != 8 )
           {
             $("#"+phone2).focus();
           }
         }
   });

}
```

What i am trying to do in above code is that : when user start entering numbers in `Cell Phone Number`  field which is having three input text boxes ,after entering 3 digit in first input box the focus will shift automatically to the next input box. 
its working fine with only one major drawback, when user enters 4'th digit it will not get entered in second input box as focus is shifting to  that input box, same happens with 8'th digit.
i have tried `keydown`(gives same result), `keyup` (validation do not work), please help.

Comment: Tried using keyup and keydown?

Comment: @sameer patil could you provide a jsfiddle?

Comment: @Evan Knowles : yes , i used both events with keydown : it eats 4th and 8th digit and with keyup it do not validate the input as it is numeric or not...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this, it will work

```
function phoneNumberValidate(phone1,match_len,phone2)
{
  //called when key is pressed in textbox
  $("#"+phone1).keypress(function (e) 
  {
    var entered_key = String.fromCharCode(e.which);
     //if the letter is not digit then display error and don't type anything
         if (e.which != 8 && e.which != 0 && (e.which < 48 || e.which > 57)) 
         {
             return false;
         }
         else
         {
          var phone=$("#"+phone1).val();
          var field_len=phone.length;
           if(field_len==match_len && e.which != 8 )
           {
             $("#"+phone2).focus().val(entered_key);

           }
         }
   });

}
```

Comment: Hi there is one small problem with this solution ...... we are testing this solution on IE 10.0.7 ... it repeats 4th and 8th digit one more time in input text box (it works fine in ff and crome ) .... please help

Comment: try without chaining method, I mean put the **$("#"+phone2).val(entered_key);** below the focus

Comment: applied not working still repeating 4th and 8th digit

Comment: can you detect the IE and remove the extra value :D

Comment: i have done this :  $("#"+phone2).focus();
                   // $("#"+phone2).val(entered_key);  it works for ie but then original problem remains for ff and crome

Comment: for IE dont use $("#"+phone2).val(entered_key); , & for other browser use this !

Answer (score 1):

I modified the code a bit and used keyup insteand. I created an example on jsbin - http://jsbin.com/gugozure/1/edit.

Let me know if this is what you wanted.

```
function phoneNumberValidate(phone1, match_len, phone2) {

$("#" + phone1).keyup(function (e) {
    if (e.which !== 8 && e.which !== 0 && (e.which < 48 || e.which > 57)) {
        return false;
    } else {
        var phone = $("#" + phone1).val();

        var field_len = phone.length;

        if (field_len == match_len && e.which != 8) {
            $("#" + phone2).focus();
        }
    }
});
}
```

Comment: it works for validation but can not retain the 4th and 8th digit .... thanks for suggetion...